# Odd error when trying to grant View All on Accounts and Contacts

Tags: permissions, profile

When I try to grant View All permissions on Accounts and Contacts...

[image]

...I am getting the following when I press save:

```
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
• Permission Read All Application Role Permissions depends on permission(s): Read All Permissions
• Permission Read All Experience History depends on permission(s): Read All Resources
```

This makes no sense to me as I have not touched either of those?

Any ideas?

Comment: There are General and Administrative Permissions as well. Did you checked them properly when providing `view all` privilege?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you attempt to grant object level permissions to a child in a Master Detail relationship. The parent in this relationship dictates object level access to the child object and you are attempting to set object level permissions directly on the child.

> Permission Read All Application Role Permissions depends on permission(s): Read All Permissions

This error means that your `Application Role Permissions` object is a child in a Master Detail relationship with an object named `Permissions`. Uncheck the object-level permissions checkboxes on the `Application Role Permissions` object.

> Permission Read All Experience History depends on permission(s): Read All Resources

This error means that your `Experience History` object is a child in a Master Detail relationship with an object named `Resources`. Uncheck the object-level permissions checkboxes on the `Experience History` object.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that somewhere you(Or someone else) have provided any related child object higher access than parent object which is now throwing you the error for the parent object permissions. Check if any of your object requires more permissions so as to remove this error. Check your objects named Application Role, Experience History, Resources.

There are for sure some other objects permission missing resulting into this error. I had faced similar issue before.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks